# Domain & Subdomain have the same title tag

Tags: seo, subdomain, ranking, google-ranking

We have 2 e-shops, one B2B and one B2C. Both of them are under the same domain. Both shops have similar products, therefore a lot of times different pages have the same title tag (since the title tag gets the value from the product name).

In this question:
[checking for duplicate title and meta description tags across multiple subdomains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85783/checking-for-duplicate-title-and-meta-description-tags-across-multiple-subdomain)
I read that

> if the content is unique on each page then it doesn't matter if titles
>   are duplicate. Titles are duplicated in the thousands daily due to the
>   fact the title tag is only so many characters and duplicates regularly
>   occur naturally, this isn't a factor.

but in our case, the content is not actually unique since we have the same products.

Do you think that is possible that issue to affect the e-shop's ranking?

Comment: Is not similar case? why you said "in our case the content is actually unique"

Comment: sorry @Goyllo. I meant the opposite. The content is not unique.

Comment: Not unique and same content is two different things, but generally if the content is nearly same, then I would say don't do that. Either your domain or subdomain will soon get low quality penalty. Google does not like to index same thing again n again, but if the product is like smartphones or something like that on which future and specification about products are same then it's totally fine, so it's depend on type of content.

Comment: Are the Titles being automatically generated for each page? Maybe there a way to differentiate the Titles somehow by adding a modifier of some sort.

Comment: It is a prestashop implementation and the titles are generated through the product names

Comment: Sorry, I am deflecting from your original question (I cannot answer if it is affecting your rankings without a more indepth analysis) but I see that Prestashop is open source software, if you discover that it is an issue, then you can have someone change the code to implement a differentiation in the Titles.

Comment: Duplicate titles are not the end f the world, however, in as much as possible, you should create unique and relevant title tags. If automatically created, then see what options exist. Title tags are important, however, this is quite common for e-commerce.

Comment: @YanGilbert At the moment, I would like to know if it can be an issue and then I can ask for changing the titles. I guess there are more cases like that in other sites.

Comment: It's difficult to answer if it is hurting you. There are so many factors that affect rankings that we do not have measurement on that it would only be speculation.
Some sites have every page with the same Title. This is obviously hurting them. But in your case, it is not so egregious.
Have you checked the rankings of your pages, comparing non-duplicated items to duplicated items?

Comment: When Google finds two pages with the same content on your site, it will generally pick one of the two to index and ignore the other.  If your two site sections duplicate pages from each other, only one will be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same content on two different pages on your site, Google will detect it and only choose one of the two to index. See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

The only user targeting for which Google supports duplicate sites is by country.  You could set up a  `.co.uk` site and a `.com.au` site that are pretty much identical and Google would show each of them only to users in their respective countries.

Without knowing how you treat the two types of users differently, it is hard to come up with a strategy to help you.  For SEO, you should probably just have one site.